# Search for occurence of any stored words within a sentence (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have not been able to find a question close enough to what I am asking, so here is my problem:

I have a list of blacklisted words stored in a MySQL table. Then I have a sentence. I would need to construct a MySQL query, where I search for occurence of any of the blacklisted words in the sentence.

If there is just one match, the search may stop, as the sentence is not acceptable.

Can anyone help me construct this query? Thanks!

### Edit

If possible, I would like to avoid jumping beween PHP and MySQL. I can have two thousands or more blacklisted words. I would like to submit my file as a string/variable into the MySql, not to build a table from it.

The closest one line SQL I get is: 
`SELECT keyword, STRCMP('this is my sentence with blacklisted word', keyword) FROM blacklist;`

Maybe, my line goes in a good direction and can be improved to simply return TRUE or FALSE if a match was found?

Comment: where do you have the sentence?

Comment: @MyDog: hi, the sentence is passed as an argument into the query. The sentence is changing, and it is passed from PHP script. I need to check if it contains any of the blacklisted words.

Comment: OP, I misread the question the first time. I see now that you may have multiple blacklisted words, so I updated my answer a little bit. This wasn't tagged with PHP, which I'm not familiar with, but take a look at my edited answer which shows how you could do this assuming your sentence is stored in a table, and not passed as a reference. It might still help.

Comment: @McAdam331: Hi and thanks for your update. Yes, you are on a good way. Because of speed reasons, I would like to avoid jumping between PHP and MySQL. I would like to to buidl one query and get the results. I need a while to digest your example, but I know, that I want to submit a string as a variable into the query.

Comment: Okay, hope you can solve it. I would recommend adding the php tag to your question, as well as editing the question to state you are using PHP. It helps someone like me, who's answer would be correct for MySQL (as it is tagged) but doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: @McAdam331: good points. I have added PHP tag and updated my question. I gave you some +1.

Comment: Hey you, genius, would you be so kind and explain why did I earn -1 from you for a legitimate question?

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori maybe the use of Locate would be a better solution, see fiddle--> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/045aad/21

Comment: right fiddle -->http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/045aad/26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I have found an answer to my own question:

`SELECT SUM( 'this is my windows xp file' LIKE CONCAT('%', keyword, '%')) AS result FROM blacklist;`

No need for multiple queries or to preprocess anything in PHP or multiple jumps between MySQL and PHP.

Comment: but the use of 'Like' is not a good solution for example: if your table "blacklist" contains the keyword "facebook" as a blacklisted word, an expression that contains the word "face" wil be rejected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a table with all blacklisted words you could construct a list of words from the sentence in php and pass it as an argument in the where clause query.

```
  $words = str_word_count($string, 1);
  $whereclause = join("','",$words);
  $whereclause  = "('".$whereclause."')";

  $query = "Select COUNT(words) from blacklisttable where words IN".$whereclause;
```

Then you can  check if the result is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

you have to break your sentense into words an check if your table contains any of those words by using `in`. case you use php, you can do something like this:

```
  $expression="is there any blacklisted word here";
  $words=str_word_count($expression, 1);
  $words=implode(",",$words);
  $sql=mysql_query("select word from table_black_list_word where word in ($words)",$db_conn);
 if($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   //case your expression do have a blacklisted word
   }else{
     //expression does not contains any blacklisted word

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using mysql `WHERE` and `LIKE` :

```
WHERE
  (
       `sentence` LIKE '%blist1%'
    OR `sentence` LIKE '%blist2%'
    OR `sentence` LIKE '%blist3%'
    OR `sentence` LIKE '%blist4%'
  )
```

Now using php you can generate the where statement from blacklisted array by.

```
$whereStatement = "";
$blackList = new Array('blist1','blist2','blist3','blist4');
$len=count($blackList);
for($i=0;$i<$len-2;$i++) {
$whereStatement+="sentence LIKE '%$blackList[$i]' ";
}
$whereStatement+="sentence LIKE '%$blackList[$len-1]' ";
$query = "(WHERE $whereStatement )";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with locate function :

```
SELECT * FROM blacklist WHERE locate(keyword, 'the sentence') > 0
```

Answer (score -2):

To search for the expression inside a sentence, you can just use a wildcard before and after the blacklisted word. Assuming your sentence is all in one column, you can filter for it in the where clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE sentenceColumn LIKE '%blacklistedWord%'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb6e5/1) example.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry OP, but I thought I misread your question. I see now that you wanted to look for any number of blacklisted words in a sentence.

The following query pulls all sentences based on whether they have one of the blacklisted words inside of the sentence. This query however will pull every occurrence of a match. In other words, if a sentence has three blacklisted word, three rows will be returned. To correct that, you can group by sentence (or sentence id, whatever matches your table).

```
SELECT sentences.*
FROM sentences
JOIN blacklisted ON sentences.sentence LIKE CONCAT('%', blacklisted.word, '%')
GROUP BY id;
```

Here is an updated [SQL fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4537fa/5) You'll notice that this checks for any sentence with the word 'blacklisted' or 'this'. Four rows should be returned.