# Find a mysql database row into a string array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, match

I have a mysql database like

```
Id | What | Name
------------
0 | fruit | apple
1 | fruit | banana
2 | fruit | orange
3 | vegetable | onion
4 | vegetable | bean
...
```

I query a website and I parse the response into an array:

```
$response = array(
0 => 'Apple is a very good fruit',
1 => 'I like vegetables, onion is my favorite',
2 => 'I eat an orange every morning, fruit i good for your health'
3 => 'I hate vegetables',
4 => 'I love banana!'
)
```

I want to match every string of the array with the right row into the database, in this case it would be:

```
$response_matched = (
0 => Array('id' => 0, 'what' => 'fruit', 'name' => 'apple'),
1 => Array('id' => 1, 'what' => 'vegetable', 'name' => 'onion'),
2 => Array('id' => 2, 'what' => 'fruit', 'name' => 'orange'),
3 => Array('id' => -1, 'what' => 'vegetable', 'name' => 'undefined'),
4 => Array('id' => 4, 'what' => 'fruit', 'name' => 'apple')
)
```

If only 'what' column match, then return just that. I also have a separate table with just what column.
Now, I'm using regex in mysql:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$string' REGEXP what AND '$string' REGEXP name LIMIT 1"
```

This actually works (not correctly if only 'what' or 'name' matches, but this is less important), but my website became pretty slow because I have to run about 15 of this searches every time at the same time, and for every script the string array size is about 15 entries, so a total of around 225 matches (and queries) at the same time, and the database size is about 1200 rows... 
The idea I have is to get all the rows at the begin of the script ("SELECT * FROM table") and then loop the results and for every loop, I loop the string array, and if it matches, I get one result. This would be less problem for the database because only 1 query per script, but I would anyway loop in 15*1100 matches which is quite a bit of work for the server...
The last idea is to get all the rows stored in a multi dimensional array like

```
$rows = array('fruit' => array(row0,row1,row2), 'vegetable'=>(row3,row4));
```

Then loop the rows to match the key ('fruit','vegetable') and if it matches then I loop that array (fruit matches, hence I loop row0,row1,row2)
Have you a different idea on how I could get the result I want? A more effective way to match?
I also would like to store the query result into memory, so that I can get it between scripts (when I run the script 15 times at the same time, I would like to be able to make a single mysql query to get the result and have it shared between the scripts). How can I achieve this? I was looking for mysql query cache... Anything else?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I drunk a bit but the solution seems to be:

1. You have a table with the following attributes / fields: Id | What | Name - I shall call it veggiesNfruits (the name sucks a bit) but you have a different table name for that (just input it below).
2. You should execute a SQL DDL statement:

   alter table veggiesNfruits add tasteDescription varchar(255);
3. Next you should execute a SQL DML statement:

   `truncate table veggiesNfruits; -- this will delete all records from a table
   insert into veggiesNfruits (What, Name, tasteDescription) values ('fruit',
   'apple', 'Apple is a very good frui'), ('fruit', 'banana', 'Bananas are for pussys') /*...rest of fruits n veggies with descriptions */; -- this will insert your records + description`
4. Avoid using `select * from blaBlahblah` -- this is pure evil and impacts parformance (although I assume that in this case you need all the fields and that is the reason of 'star', instead use select [field1], [field2] from ...)
5. Load SQL results to array, do not lookup / join description of veggie / fruit, just print / output array["description"].
   Hope it helps.

Ultimately I think that you should read about databases / tables desing an maybe have the following tables instead:

`create table plants(veg_id int primary key, veg_name varchar(255), veg_pln_id int references plant_types(pln_id)); -- maybe also veg_description`

`create table plant_types(pln_id int primary key, pln_description varchar(255);`
`insert into plant_types(pln_description) values('fruit'), ('vegetable');
insert into plants(veg_name, veg_pln_id) values('apple', 1), ('onion', 2);
insert into plants(veg_name, veg_pln_id) values ('bean',select pln_id from plant_types where pln_description='vegtable');`

Comment: My english is bad, in fact you didn't understand what I'm looking for. The string array that I want to match with the database, is the result of a http call to a website, and it might change, I have not control over it. And the match can occur several times with the same row. For example if the array is (banana is a good fruit, i like to eat fruit and banana), then both of the elements should match the dame row (fruit, banana).

Answer (score 0):

My english is bad! But i understand your question.

Why do you want matching string `$response` with DB on real-time request? If it is not necessary, i think you need to make a table to save the responses, then make the process by crontab, make the loop for it. Handle it in a sequential way, that will better.

And if it really necessary to matching response real-time, i think your system require many processes (by java, nodejs, etc... and multi-threads) to solve this problem. Only PHP & MySQL can't do more of thing you want.

** Updated: The solution in last of question is not bad. I thinked it immediately after when i know the question, but i not sure your real needs.

Comment: I have the client giving an input, the input is searched on different website (each website is search on different script to have asynchronous responses), than the responses are matched with the database to link every response with the row of the database which contains extra info (in my example would be color, weight,...) and also logical connections with other tables. I want all this info displayed to the client as soon as the websites response, so I need a real time matching and the only way is through string matching.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you didn't forget to add indexes to What and Name column, you'll get huge performance impact

ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE unique_index(What, Name);

just to name it a few alternatives. look at this question [Search for occurence of any stored words within a sentence (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565958/search-for-occurence-of-any-stored-words-within-a-sentence-mysql)

SELECT *, SUM('$string' LIKE CONCAT('%', What, '%')) as what, SUM('$string' LIKE CONCAT('%', Name, '%')) as name from table;

or, preprocess string into comma separated

$string = implode(",", $string);

then

SELECT * FROM searh WHERE What IN ($string) and Name in ($string) LIMIT 1;

not sure which one going faster at least index will help much